# Standalone wiremock server as spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, docker, mocking, mockserver, wiremock-standalone

I am trying to make a mock service as a spring boot application.
Can I use standalone mock server inside a spring boot application?
When I tried to run a mock server on any port inside the spring boot application it throws the "Address already bound exception"
Is there a way to over come that so that I can have a mockservice running as a spring boot docker container and just configure the urls I want to mock.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you would want to avoid any starter that brings up a container/server. Initially, I have only these two dependencies: `com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8:2.31.0` and `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json`. Optionally, confirm you don't want to run any server(s): `spring.main.web-application-type: none`.

Finally, declare a config file to setup WireMock:

```java
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties(WireMockConfig.ApplicationProps.class)
public class WireMockConfig {
  private final ApplicationProps props;

  @Bean
  public WireMockServer mockServer() {
    return new WireMockServer(WireMockConfiguration.options().port(8081));
  }
}
```

...and a listener to start the server:

```java
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationListener {
  private final WireMockServer server;

  @EventListener
  public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
    server.start();
  }
}
```